# What does "render._keywords['globals']['render'] = render" mean in web.py skeleton code?

Tags: python, web.py

What does "render._keywords['globals']['render'] = render" mean in web.py skeleton code?
http://webpy.org/skeleton/0.3

Answer (score 2):

It means that `render` will be accesible inside templates to be able to render nested templates.

It is then used in templates/listing.html to render item template

```
$def with (items)

$for item in items:
    $:render.item(item)
```